# Why am I getting a negative balance after subtracting values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula to subtract several cells from 1 cell and I am getting a result of -2.27374E-13. The formula is `D235-E235-F235-G235-H235-I235-J235`, each column has a dollar value and no matter how I try to calculate it it still comes out `(0.00)`.

```
D235 = 2386.16
E235 =    0.00
F235 = 1431.70
G235 =    0.00
H235 =    0.00
I235 =  954.46
J235 =    0.00
```

Comment: Colleen, please include a screenshot of the sheet, or a formatted list of the values. It it difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: 2386.16  0.00  1431.70  0.00  0.00  954.46  0.00  (0.00)

Comment: 2386.16, 954.46 and 1431.70 can't be represented exactly in binary floating-point, hence the accumulated error after many calculations may be larger. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Answer (score 3):

That number you're getting is about as close to nothing as the spreadsheet can display...  -0.000000000000227374, if I've counted zeros correctly. This is due to issues with [floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Somewhere on the spreadsheet a number is calculated that needs to be rounded to fewer decimal places, which can be done by the [ROUND function in Excel](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-round-function).

To understand this, manually divide 1 by 3 (long division). The result is 0.333... Now *multiply* that answer by 3, and you should get back 1 (multiplying by 3 is the inverse of dividing by it). However, the result is 0.999... , not 1.000... This shows that the two results are equivalent, but 0.999... is *not* the way most people want to see the number expressed.